# Guidance on using JSONB vs normalized columns in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb

If a key is used (or has a value) only 40% of the time in a JSON, do I still create a column for that key in Postgres? The online literature states to use a normalized column when the value for a key is always there, but I couldn't find any guidance on what to do when a key is filled most of the time or a threshold. I am trying to find out when to prefer JSONB over column, To paraphrase, what is the threshold for how often a key should have a value to qualify having its own column.

Comment: For me the first tests are whether the key will be used to filter in queries, join to other tables, or needs its integrity enforced via an FK relationship.  If it is only for filtering in queries, then I go by whether there is any performance advantage to "promoting" it to a regular column.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'll keep this in mind